# Давай на выходным следующих встретимся. Я имею в виду(,) через неделю

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Давай на выходным следующих встретимся. Я имею в виду(,) через неделю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Давай на выходным следующих встретимся. Я имею в виду, **через неделю.***

Здесь сложное предложение, вторая часть **неполная**: Я имею в виду, (встретимся) через неделю. Делается пауза.

Предложение нельзя рассматривать **как простое**, так как здесь нет управления: *я имею в виду (что?) неделю.*

Это БСП, отношения **изъяснительные**, обозначены запятой.

Первая часть по значению близка к **вводному** предложению, а основное содержание во второй части. Поэтому ставится запятая.